# ROR API Trying to create a zip code search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

So far I have separate zip+5 and zip+9 searches running. I want to create a search that returns results as specific as the input, and more specific when possible (user inputs a +5, they get results containing +5 and +9, user inputs a +9 gets back only matching +9's)

Here's what I have so far

```
scope :by_postal9, ->(postal_code) { where('postal_code = ?', (postal_code)) } #9 digit
scope :by_postal5, ->(postal_code) { where('postal_code = ?', (postal_code[0..4])) } #5 digit
scope :by_postal, ->(postal_code) { where('postal_code = ?', (postal_code[0..4])) or where('postal_code = ?', (postal_code)) } #all lengths
```

Working with a dataset of

```
ID \ postal_code
1  \ 92110-4441
2  \ 92110
3  \ 92110-4441
```

My 9 digit search seems to be the best one, it has no problems returning matching results for either +5 or +9 searches, but ONLY returns exact matches (searching postal9 with 92110 yields 1 result, searching with 92110-4441 yields 2 results, non-overlapping)

The 5 digit search operates as you might expect, and upon input of a 9 digit zip, returns matches for 5 digit results, but ONLY 5 digit results (search postal5 with 92110-4441 returns 1 result, ID 2)

The last example is probably just trash, but was my final effort in getting combined results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `LIKE`?

```
scope :by_postal, ->(postal) { where('postal_code LIKE ?', "#{postal}%") }
```

If your `postal` is 5-digit it returns 5-digit and 9-digit variants. If 9-digit -- 9-digit only.

Answer (score 0):

I would use separate scopes

```
by_postal, ->(postal_code) { where('postal_code LIKE ?', "%#{}%") }
by_length, ->(length) { where('LEN(postal_code) = ?', length) }
```

- for +5 `by_postal('211').by_length(5)`
- for +9 `by_postal('211').by_length(9)`
- for both `by_postal('211')`

Comment: I am not sure `LEN` function is portable across different sql servers